# TinyMCE 5 translate "Link list"

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

The TinyMCE docs mention translations via language files, but I'm not sure how to change a label text with the default (en_US) language.

Seen in the screenshot is the "Link plugin" overlay. Here I want to change the label for "Link list" to "Articles". When inspecting the label in the frontend, I cannot see any specific label markup (key, or name) for this particular dropdown. Does that mean that it might me hardcoded somewhere and I cannot even change it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
tinymce.addI18n('en',{ 
"Link list": "Articles"
});
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! The documentation is not really clear about that. I was looking for a language handle like `something.label".